# writing a json object to buffer in nodejs

Tags: node.js, buffer, amqp, cloudamqp

I am trying to use [amqplib](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/) a `AMQP 0-9-1 library and client for Node.JS`

and I have a question about buffers. How can I write a JSON object to them.

The [channel.publish](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_publish) requires `content` in the form of a buffer.

And after I publish the message, when I [consume](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_consume) them in the worker, how can I extract the message again from the buffer to get the JavaScript object back.

The `message` object passed to the consumer is of the form

```
{
  content: Buffer,
  fields: Object,
  properties: Object
}
```

where `content` is the content we passed to the publisher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSON.parse(message.content)
```

Should work